# Future.get() does not return

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have the following piece of code:

```
public class Test {
   List<Future> future = new ArrayList<Future>();

   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

     Adapter b1 = new Adapter();
     final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

      for(//iterate for number of files) {  
         while(data exists in file) {
            //Call a function to process and update values in db 
            future.add(threadPool.submit(new Xyz(b1)));
            //read next set of data in file;
         }
       }

      try {
         for(Future f: future) { 
            f.get(); 
         }
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
         throw e;
      }    
   }
}

class Xyz implements Runnable {
   private Adapter a1;

   public Xyz(Adapter al) {
      this.a1=a1;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      try { 
         a1.abc();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
      } 
   }
}
```

When the number of files is 1 (for loop runs for 1 time), the code runs fine.

But, when the number of files increases, the code never returns back from `future.get()` method.

Comment: Are you aware that you are invoking `newCachedThreadPool` within a nested loop?

Comment: are you sure that there isn't a problem in your implementation of the futures run method? A deadlock maybe which occurs because multiple futures try to access the same exclusive resources?

Comment: Philip, evrything runs fine if i comment out the future.get()

Comment: Whatever `a1.abc()` is doing blocks and your `future.get()` call blocks accordingly.

Comment: edwin, m newbie to multithreading, does invoking newCachedThreadPool be a problem ?

I made some changes like 
        
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
 Adapter b1 = new Adapter();
           final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
//rest are same

but still same problem !!

Comment: a1.abc() works fine without future.get() :(

Comment: @abhinay The idea of a thread pool is that you have one pool, and submit many tasks to it => you should only use one instance of the pool.

Comment: @assylias ok !!..gotcha !!

but still this doesn't solve my problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Callable::call` / `Runable::run` does not return. Otherwise the corresponding future would not block.

Additional  executor.shutdown or `future.cancel` will thow an `InterruptedException` to stop the thread processing the object you submitted but it is up to you if to catch it or not. Your are responsible for making the jobs you submitted stop.

When you submit thousands Callables/Runnables to a `CachedExecutor` that it might spawn so many threads that your machine gets so slow that you think it takes forever. But you would have noticed that.

When dealing with an undefined number of parallelizable tasks i suggest to use  a `FixedThreadPool` with not much more threads that there are cpu cores.

Edit: Therefore when you set a breakpoints at `a1.abc();` and step forward you will probably find out that it never returns.

Answer (score 1):

> just out of curiosity.. do i need to shutdown the executor somewhere ??

Yes, and this is likely the problem.  Each `Future.get()` will block until the corresponding task is complete, then once all the tasks are complete your `main` thread will exit.  But your java process will *not* exit because the thread pool threads are still active in the background.  You should shut down the executor once you have finished with it, most likely as the last thing in your `main` method.

I also note that you're submitting many tasks that wrap the *same* `Adapter` instance and all call its `abc()` method - check that there's nothing in there that will deadlock when called simultaneously in more than one thread.

Comment: but it works perfectly fine for a single file, stucks for more than one file, don't understand this behaviour .